# Bash Redirection Operations

Tags: bash

I have seen the commands `<<< "$@"` and `< <(printf '%s\n' "$@")`. Are they both described as Redirection Operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<<<
```

is a *here string* Similar to here documents: The word after `<<<` and a newline are passed to the standard input of a command.
Syntax: `command <<< "some sentence"`, like

```
echo "some sentence" | command
```

but without the overhead of the subshell.

---

```
command < <(othercommand)
```

Same thing as

```
othercommand | command
```

but without subshelling 'command'. Uses file redirection `<` to redirect a file created by process substitution `<()`. The space between `<` and `<( )` is important to avoid ambiguity (is it a heredoc, is it a redirected PS?).

Comment: Seems that `<<<` is specific to gawk but `< <(printf '%s\n' "$@")` is not.  Right?

Comment: @konmi No, both are evaluated by the shell (bash).

Comment: I always thought that `printf '%s\n' "$@" | command` and `command < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")` are more portable than `command <<< "$@"`.

Comment: Of these, `printf '%s\n' "$@" | command` is by far the most portable (it'll work in any POSIX shell). `<<< "$@"` is much less portable (it'll work in bash, zsh, and ksh, but not basic shells like dash). BTW, I wouldn't recommend using `$@` here; its purpose is to get each argument as a separate string, but `<<<` only takes one string, so the arguments just get mashed together. ``<<< "$*"`` would be better, because `$*` indicates that you *want* the args mashed together. `command < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")` is the least portable; `<` is universal, but `<( )` won't even work in bash-as-sh mode.

Comment: Much appreciate your comments on `"$*"` and `<( )`.